# Is it possible to install Apple Mail without installing the full Ventura OS?

Tags: mail.app, ventura

I use my laptop for work and I don't want to risk incompatibilities. I have been burned before.

However, there are some features of apple mail that I would like to use, hence the question.

Comment: What OS do you currently have?

Comment: So you want to install the Ventura version (version 16) of macOS Ventura only? This is the same Apple Mail version as the one in Monterey BTW.

Comment: @Tetsujin macOS Monterey (12.6)

Comment: @AlexIxeras According to https://www.apple.com/macos/ventura/ they have added: Undo send, Schedule send, Follow up, etc... Have they been there all along? I just checked and could not see any of these new features

Comment: Mail isn't available as a separate download, it's bundled in the OS, so the point is moot really. I doubt trying to pick the bones out of one version to manually dump into the other is going to be a joyful quest.

Comment: @Rojj I just took a closer look. While both Mail apps are v16.0 they are different builds (Monterey 3696.120.41.1.1, Ventura 3731.200.110.1.12). That, along with the OS features benwiggy mentioned in his answer, might be the reason that those features you're after are not in the Monterey version. I doubt you may be able to copy the Ventura Mail version and install it in Monterey to see if that provides you with the features, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the application 'features' that Apple introduces are not part of the  application itself!

The features are added to the Operating System, and the new app then calls on those features.

So it is extremely unlikely that a new app could work on an old system.

However, as for 'incompatibilities': the risk is very low when moving from one OS to the next one; but it increases as the delta change increases.(e.g. jumping from a much older OS to much newer one.)

It is always important to make sure that the software you use has compatible updates for the latest OS before you upgrade. The easiest way of doing this is by staying up-to-date.

While staying fixed on one OS version, and not upgrading, will give you a 'stable' system, if you ever need to update something *(--and you will--)*, then the whole thing will need tearing down and replacing.

Software is like a house plant: it needs constant maintenance to survive.